# Why is it possible to use `$` to subset SpatialPolygonsDataFrame?

Tags: r, spatial

When I have a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object, I know that I can get to the data two ways:

```
spatial_df@data$column
spatial_df$column
```

However I don't understand why the second way is possible. I thought that I must access the `data` slot using `@`? Is this something unique about the `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` class, or is it something about S4 object in general?

One possible answer is in the [`sp` documentations](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/sp.pdf), which mentions the method `[` for the `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` class. However, since `$` is equivalent to `[[`, NOT to `[`, I'm not sure that's the answer.

Comment: Do some more reading, please. It should include articles and blogs that include the search terms "S4" and "S3". Your conclusions regarding `$` are as stated incorrect or at the very least incomplete. For the specific look at `?"["`

Comment: My understanding of `$` comes from [Hadley's Advanced R book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html). Quote: "$ is a shorthand operator, where x$y is equivalent to x[["y", exact = FALSE]]"

Comment: Yes. Notice the second part. As I said, "incomplete". The point which is critical is that the `"y"` will not be evaluated, whereas if you had put the name an object in there as the second argument it would have been evaluated and the value rather than the name would have been the basis for the result.

Comment: @BondedDust So I have figured out the answer below. If I'm not wrong, `$` behaves this way due to the implementation within the `sp` package, and has nothing to do with S4 in general. However, you did recommend me to read more about S4 and S3 in general, so I'm worried that I might have got something wrong still.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that this behavior of `$` is implemented by the `Spatial` class in the `sp` package, and is not a feature of general S4 object.

The long answer (how I find out about this):

- Use `showMethods("$")` to find out about all the methods of the generic `$`.

> ```
> The result shows:
> Function: $ (package base)
> x="C++Class"
> x="envRefClass"
> x="Module"
> x="Raster"
> x="refObjectGenerator"
> x="Spatial"
> x="SpatialGDAL"
> x="SpatialPoints"
> x="SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
>     (inherited from: x="Spatial")
> ```

So we know that `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame-class` inherits `$` from `Spatial-class`. We go to the root by:

- `getMethod("$", "Spatial")`, which shows the implementation of `$` for `Spatial-class` as follows:

> ```
> Method Definition:
>
> function (x, name) 
> {
>     if (!("data" %in% slotNames(x))) 
>         stop("no $ method for object without attributes")
>     x@data[[name]]
> }
> <environment: namespace:sp>
> ```

Therefore, `spatial_df$col_name` is a shortcut for `spatial_df@data[["col_name"]]`

Comment: That implies that `spatial_df` is an S4 object but that one of its nodes, the one named: "data",  has an S3-style list as contents. The definition of the `$`-method is basically the same as that of the usual `$`-method as `[[name]]`.